# What does @ symbol at the end of a shared object mean?

Tags: unix, shared-objects

I am using Ubuntu and when I list the libraries under /usr/lib/ I see that some of them have numbers and/or @ symbol at the end. For example libgc.so.1@ or libgettextlib.so@
Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: It means that these are symlinks (if you use `ls -l libgc.so.1`, you'll see it pointing to a different name). The `@` is not actually on the end of the filename; it's just displayed by `ls` when given the `-F` option, which some operating systems configure an alias to enable by default.

Comment: As this is more a usage question than a programming question, by the way, a better forum for it would be http://superuser.com/.

Comment: How can I carry it there?

Comment: The easy way to migrate the question, at this point, is to wait for more folks to vote to close it via migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ls` command try to give you some hints about the nature of the names it lists, depending on version of `ls` and the options you give to it.

For example a trailing `/` is sometimes added to mean that the object is a directory. A trailing `@` means that it is a symbolic link. `ls -l` will show you the referred file.

What is a symbolic link ? A symbolic link is a file whose content is not data that you can use freely, but the name of another file. So when you try to manipulate the symbolic link, the system manipulates the file that it refers to. This is an indirection. There is also links that are slightly more integrated and invisible to you much more like an alias.

Here is how to experiment

```
$ touch foo
$ ln -s foo bar
$ ls -l foo bar
lrwxr-xr-x  1 yunes  wheel  3 16 jan 10:45 bar -> foo
-rw-r--r--  1 yunes  wheel  0 16 jan 10:45 foo
```

This means that `foo` is a file (empty actually), and `bar` is not a regular file but a *name* that points to `foo`. Now:

```
$ echo "hello" >> foo
$ cat foo
hello
$ cat bar
hello
$
```

This to show you that using `foo` or `bar` is almost the same...

Comment: You might also run `ls -F` to show the sigil added, while demonstrating output from `ls` with various arguments.